# What is the max number of characters that are available to the comment field?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I did a google search and read about 20 different posts, but still haven't found what the limit of characters in a comment field is.  I checked Excel's help files, and the Microsoft website, and that information is not readily available.

Does anyone know what the maximum number of characters that are available to the comment field is?

I'm using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

according to the help file, the max number of characters is 255

Answer (score 0):

It must be way more than 255 characters. I have copy pasted whole pages off the net into these little yellow boxes that sometimes stretch down 400 rows. This would equate to 1000's of words at least. Sometimes these boxes freeze and I have to delete and redo them. My current spreadsheet must be loaded with at least 50,000 of these notes. Best idea for docco work I've ever come across. Although search does not scan info within these notes fields which is a pain at times.